# Using Quotations Marks in a title in Highslide JS

Tags: javascript, highslide

I am using Highslide as my picture viewer for my website and want to be able to use quotations mark in some text within my Title. When is simply put the relevant text into quotations marks all text beyond the 1st quotation mark is missing. Would appreciate some help on this matter - examples below:

```
<a class='highslide' href='../g94/18.jpg'
    title="If I put text here and want "This piece in quotation marks" to make it stand out"
    onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
<img src='../g94/s18.jpg' alt=''/></a>
```

The result is - If I put text here and want

or;

```
<a class='highslide' href='../g94/18.jpg'
    title="If I put text here and want \"This piece in quotation marks\" to make it stand out"
    onclick="return hs.expand(this, miniGalleryOptions1)">
<img src='../g94/s18.jpg' alt=''/></a>
```

The result is - If I put text here and want \

Thanks John

Answer (score 0):

The simplest fix is to use single quotes for the title attribute:

```
title='If I put text here and want "This piece in quotation marks" to make it stand out'
```